# The chrome works well with live streaming ,but the firefox and other explorer just keep loading all the time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm streaming a fragmented mp4 to the video tag with websocket.

The chrome works well with live streaming ,but the firefox and other explorer keep loading all the time.And there is no error hint is in the console at all.
The fragmented mp4 is sent frame by frame as "[ftyp-moov-moof-mdat],[moof-mdat],[moof-mdat] etc" through websocket from the server side.

Here is the code of client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MSE Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>MSE Demo</h1>
<div>
    <video controls height="80%" muted></video>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://"+window.location.hostname+":5012");
    websocket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
    var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    var buffer;
    var queue = [];
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(e) {
        video.play();
        buffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.428032"');
        buffer.addEventListener('updatestart', function(e) { console.log('updatestart: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
        buffer.addEventListener('update', function(e) { console.log('update: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
        buffer.addEventListener('updateend', function(e) { console.log('updateend: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
        buffer.addEventListener('error', function(e) { console.log('error: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
        buffer.addEventListener('abort', function(e) { console.log('abort: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
        buffer.addEventListener('updateend', function() { // Note: Have tried 'updateend'

            if (queue.length > 0 && !buffer.updating) {
                buffer.appendBuffer(queue.shift());
            }

        });
    }, false);
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(e) { console.log('sourceopen: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceended', function(e) { console.log('sourceended: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceclose', function(e) { console.log('sourceclose: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
    mediaSource.addEventListener('error', function(e) { console.log('error: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
    websocket.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        if (typeof e.data !== 'string') {
            if (buffer.updating || queue.length > 0) {
                queue.push(e.data);
            } else {
                buffer.appendBuffer(e.data);
            }
         }
    }, false);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect it plays the live stream frame by frame in the firefox.

Comment: For the browser that don't appear to be working have you tried to use the inspection tool or the network tab to ensure the media is being appended / streamed?

Comment: There are many logs "updateend" being printed in the client console ,so I make sure media is appended.

Comment: add a console.log where you `buffer.appendBuffer(queue.shift());`, `queue.push(e.data);` and `buffer.appendBuffer(e.data);` ... does it look like it's doing the right thing in the right order? I wonder if it has to do with firefox autoplay settings https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1238033 - as for "other explorers" if that means IE11, then forget about it, IE11 probably doesn't support half the API you are using anyway

Comment: I think it work as the right order since the chrome work perfect . “Other explorers” means some explorers like "microsoft edge" except IE that does not support mse. I wonder if it has to do with “mediaSource.endOfStream()” in firefox and others？ But  I fail to append data any more after “mediaSource.endOfStream()” called.

Comment: Is there anybody help me out?